# Error when trying to save record using the post method

Tags: c#

When I click on the save button it generates the error as below and does not enter the httppost "SaveRegistro"

"InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Domain.Model.Administrativo.Empresa'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Record types must have a single primary constructor. Alternatively, give the 'empresa' parameter a non-null default value."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da1W5.png)

The error in the message says to create an empty constructor, but when creating the empty constructor it doesn't accept it either.

follow the code below:

```
namespace back_office.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class EmpresaController : Controller
{
    #region Parametros

    private readonly RepositorioTiAntenado _repositorio;
    private readonly WebSite _webSite;


    #endregion

    #region Construtores

    public EmpresaController(RepositorioTiAntenado repositorio, WebSite webSite)
    {
        _repositorio = repositorio;
        _webSite = webSite;

    }

    

    #endregion

    #region Metodos

    private Empresa Empresa()
    {
        return new Empresa(_repositorio);
    }

    #endregion

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Consultar(int id = 0)
    {
            var retorno = await Empresa().Consultar(_webSite.EmpresaId);

            return View(retorno);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SalvarRegistro(Empresa empresa)
    {
        try
        {
            var retorno = await Empresa().Alterar(empresa.EmpresaId, empresa);

            return View(retorno);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var ListaJson = new List<string>
            {
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(empresa)
            };
            throw;
        }
    }
}
}
```

exemple class:

```
namespace Domain.Model.Administrativo
{
public partial class Empresa : spConsultarEmpresa
{
    #region Parâmetros Internos

    private readonly RepositorioTiAntenado _repositorio;
    private string _entidade { get { return "Empresa"; } }

    #endregion

    #region Construtores

    public Empresa(RepositorioTiAntenado repositorio)
    {
        _repositorio = repositorio;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Propriedades

    #endregion

    #region Métodos CRUD

    public async Task<Empresa> Consultar(int id)
    {

        var retorno = await _repositorio.Consultar<Empresa>(_entidade, id);

        return retorno;

    }

    public async Task<T> ConsultarGenerico<T>(int id, string requisicao)
    {
        return await _repositorio.Consultar<T>(_entidade, requisicao, id);
    }

    public async Task<List<Empresa>> ConsultarLista()
    {
        return await _repositorio.ConsultarLista<Empresa>(_entidade);
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> ConsultarListaGenerico<T>(int id, string requisicao)
    {
        return await _repositorio.ConsultarLista<T>(_entidade, requisicao, id);
    }

    public async Task<Empresa> Inserir(Empresa empresa)
    {
        return await _repositorio.Inserir<Empresa>(_entidade, empresa);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Alterar(int id, Empresa empresa)
    {
        return await _repositorio.Alterar<Empresa>(_entidade, id, empresa);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Inativar(int id, Empresa empresa)
    {
        return await _repositorio.Inativar<Empresa>(_entidade, id, empresa);
    }


    #endregion

}

#region Classes padrão

public class spConsultarEmpresa
{
    [Key]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* obrigatório")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome Fantasia")]
    public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(18, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "CNPJ")]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Inscricao Estadual")]
    public string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data Abertura")]
    public DateTime DataAbertura { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* obrigatório")]
    [MaxLength(256, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* obrigatório")]
    [MaxLength(9, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "CEP")]
    public string CEP { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* obrigatório")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Bairro")]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Complemento")]
    public string Complemento { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* obrigatório")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
    public string Cidade { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Estado")]
    public string Estado { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(14, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Celular")]
    public string Celular { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Whatsapp")]
    public string Whatsapp { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Instagram")]
    public string Instagram { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Facebook")]
    public string Facebook { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "LinkedIn")]
    public string LinkedIn { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256, ErrorMessage = "* máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Logo")]
    public string Logo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ativo")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
}

public class spConsultarListaEmpresa
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome Fantasia")]
    public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CNPJ")]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Inscricao Estadual")]
    public string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data Abertura")]
    public DateTime DataAbertura { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CEP")]
    public string CEP { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bairro")]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Complemento")]
    public string Complemento { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
    public string Cidade { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estado")]
    public string Estado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Celular")]
    public string Celular { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Whatsapp")]
    public string Whatsapp { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Instagram")]
    public string Instagram { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Facebook")]
    public string Facebook { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "LinkedIn")]
    public string LinkedIn { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Logo")]
    public string Logo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ativo")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
}
#endregion


}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. [Edit] your question and add the `Empresa` class.

Comment: I put the class, but the problem is occurring when I click on save and it tries to read the constructor.
When exiting the constructor it generates this error.

Comment: It doesn't have a parameterless constructor which is why you are getting the error. However, that class is doing far too many things. It should only have properties in it, nothing more. It absolutely should not have a repository class.

Comment: Have you tried to add [ApiController] attribute on top of the controller?

Comment: @dimmits How would that help? The error message explicitly says what the problem is.

Comment: @DavidG As I said in the request above, even adding a constructor above without a parameter, the error is occurring.

Comment: @dimmits This controller is from the web I have two applications
API and WEB the controller that is giving the problem is from the web.
When it tries to read the constructor it generates the error.

Comment: @DavidG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#binding-source-parameter-inference
also, I just checked in my project if I remove this attribute and the [frombody] I get the same exact error.

Comment: what is the difference between the two applications web and api? @thiagogcorreabotelho

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a [FromBody] so the compiler knows where you get the data from

`[HttpPost] public async Task<IActionResult> SalvarRegistro([FromBody]Empresa empresa)`

Comment: First of all, this is not going to help. `FromBody` is already the default way a parameter will be taken in a POST method. Secondly, the error message shown above clearly shows the framework has gotten past that stage and is already trying to deserialise into the class.